# Difficulty creating new list grouping by a key using itertools in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have list of dictionaries as below

```
dataset={"users": [
    {"id": 20, "loc": "Chicago", "st":"4", "sectors": [{"sname": "Retail"}, {"sname": "Manufacturing"}, {"sname": null}]}, 
    {"id": 21, "loc": "Frankfurt", "st":"4", "sectors": [{"sname": null}]}, 
    {"id": 22, "loc": "Berlin", "st":"6", "sectors": [{"sname": "Manufacturing"}, {"sname": "Banking"},{"sname": "Agri"}]}, 
    {"id": 23, "loc": "Chicago", "st":"2", "sectors": [{"sname": "Banking"}, {"sname": "Agri"}]},
    {"id": 24, "loc": "Bern", "st":"1", "sectors": [{"sname": "Retail"}, {"sname": "Agri"}]},
    {"id": 25, "loc": "Bern", "st":"4", "sectors": [{"sname": "Retail"}, {"sname": "Agri"}, {"sname": "Banking"}]}
    ]}
```

I tried below code to remove loc, sectors from above lists
so that my list would contain only id and loc

```
fs_loc = []
for g, items in itertools.groupby(data['users'], lambda x: (x['id'],x['loc'])):
    fs_loc.append({ 'id': g[0], 'loc': g[1] })
print(fs_loc)
```

From this, how can I create new list such that it will have list of id's and the count of them that were grouped by locations like below.

```
{"locations": [
    {"loc": "Chicago","count":2,"ids": [{"id": "20"}, {"id": "23"}]}, 
    {"loc": "Bern","count":2,"ids": [{"id": "24"}, {"id": "25"}]}, 
    {"loc": "Frankfurt","count":1,"ids": [{"id": "21"}]}, 
    {"loc": "Berlin","count":1,"ids": [{"id": "21"}]}    
    ]}
```

I found this difficulty in making the list as above using itertools, probably I might be missing some better approach on achieving as above, could you please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass a sorted sequence to `itertools.groupby`.

According to [`itertools.groupby` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

> ...
>   Generally, the iterable needs to already be sorted on the same key
>   function.
>
> The operation of groupby() is similar to the uniq filter in Unix. It
>   generates a break or new group every time the value of the key
>   function changes (which is why it is usually necessary to have sorted
>   the data using the same key function). That behavior differs from
>   SQL’s GROUP BY which aggregates common elements regardless of their
>   input order.

```
byloc = lambda x: x['loc']

it = (
    (loc, list(user_grp))
    for loc, user_grp in itertools.groupby(
        sorted(dataset['users'], key=byloc), key=byloc
    )
)
fs_loc = [
    {'loc': loc, 'ids': [x['id'] for x in grp], 'count': len(grp)}
    for loc, grp in it
]
```

---

`fs_loc` →

```
[
    {'count': 1, 'loc': 'Berlin', 'ids': [22]},
    {'count': 2, 'loc': 'Bern', 'ids': [24, 25]},
    {'count': 2, 'loc': 'Chicago', 'ids': [20, 23]},
    {'count': 1, 'loc': 'Frankfurt', 'ids': [21]}
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try this now

Comment: Hi falsetru! I have a question, can we also add st values with the id's inside the grp ? I tried fs_loc = [
    {'loc': loc, 'ids': [x['id'],x['st'] for x in grp], 'count': len(grp)}
    for loc, grp in it
]
 It is throwing error, could you please suggest?

Comment: fs_loc should appear to have 'ids':[{id,st},{id,st}] .. may be like this?

Comment: @SathishPanduga, Could  you post a separate question with exact desired output? (The output should be valid python literals)

Comment: @SathishPanduga, I am going to sleep. So response will take long. But with a separate question, other people can see and help you to solve the problem.

Comment: Ok.. Thanks a lot once again for your time :) Have a sound sleep!

Comment: Hi falsetru!.. I have some difficulty posting the question with my id(I get error), so I had to create from my office email and post a question related to combinations.. May I request you to kindly check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34288938/how-to-get-the-item-count-for-the-combinations-of-list-of-items-from-python-dict ?

Comment: @SathishPanduga, I answered there.

Comment: Thank you so much @falsetru